# finding last row of highlighted cell

Tags: excel, vba, cell, highlight

How do i find what the last row of of a column that is highlighted?
Currently I only know how to find last row that is used.

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: in place of `1` put `Selection.Column`

Answer (score 2):

You are not 100% correct with your statement - with your current code you will get the row number of the last row of column A (that's what the `1` in your statement stands for) - not neccessarily the last row in use of the whole sheet.
If you want to know the last row of a specific column, just change this 1 to the column number you are interested. Probably with *"highlighted"* you mean the active cell, so that would be

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Activecell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
```

A rather complete discussion about how to get the last row/column/cell can be found at [Find last used cell in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba)

---

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your requirement correctly then you will need an approach like this.

`lngLastRow = Selection.Cells(Selection.Cells.Count, 1).Row`